# Getting the user's position in the leaderboard

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

Query stopped working (getting the user's position in the leaderboard):

```
SELECT 
        `rank`, `uid`, `battleWinScore` 
        FROM
            (SELECT 
             @rank:=@rank+1 AS `rank`, `uid`, `battleWinScore` 
             FROM
             `rating`, (SELECT @rank := 0) r 
             ORDER BY `battleWinScore` DESC 
            ) t 
        WHERE uid = 572;
```

In the rating table, we need to get the user's position by field `battleWinScore`.
I am absolutely not good at mysql. Help =)

Comment: Please provide your tables structure and sample data for any one will help you

Comment: What MySQL version your have?

Comment: You emulate ROW_NUMBER, not RANK.

Comment: Your query looks working: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=bd36977d177ec4c691aa8b5a71514972&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: Thanks to all those who responded! The suggested solution helped.

Comment: Please explain what "stopped working" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, just use `row_number()` (or `rank()`, if you want to consistently allow ties).

```
select *
from (
    select uid, battleWinScore, rank() over(order by battleWinScore desc) rn
    from rating
) r
where uid = 572
```

In earlier versions, I would recommend a correlated subquery rather than user variables:

```
select uid, battleWinScore
    (select count(*) + 1 from rating r1 where r1.battleWinScore > r.battleWinScore) as rn
from rating r
where uid = 572
```